# initialization method on plugin interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, plugins, inversion-of-control

I have following interface for plugin:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    IInitializedPlugin Initialize(PluginInitialization pluginInitialization);
}
```

application can get `IPlugin` instance (from IOC container in this case) but to get `IInitializedPlugin` instance it has to call `Initialize` method. `PluginInitialization` is simple structure with configuration for plugin. Then `IInitializedPlugin` has actual plugin functionality. How can this design be improved?

Comment: This is not related with Java.

Comment: Well you could alter the design slightly (really, it doesn't _change_ the design so much as it _renames_ types) so consumers provide an `IPluginFactory` which produces an `IPlugin`. The factory has a `Create` method which requires an `IPluginConfiguration` object and returns an instantiated/initialized `IPlugin` object.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - IPluginFactory, Create and IPlugin are better names certainly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well your design can surely work, [PRISM](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) *(Desktop Application Framework by Microsoft)* uses a similar approach for initializing Modules, nevertheless if you are using .NET for development i would consider using [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) *(Managed Extensibility Framework)* for this because using a certain IoC container will couple the plugins with that specific container, you can learn more about this by reading the fourth comment by [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) in this [Article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: MEF is not required for avoiding dependency on dependency injection container in plugin. Mark Seemann is always good read, thanks for link.